# codeigniter bcc doesn't work

Tags: codeigniter, email, bcc

Codeigniter "bcc" doesn't work, But the same code with "to" works just fine! Any suggestions why this happens and how to fix it?

Here's my code:

```
        $email = "myEmail@myWebsite.com";

        $subject = "my subject";
        $message = "my message";

        $this->email->set_mailtype("html"); // In my actual code this is needed

        $this->email->from('myWebsiteEmail@myWebsite.com', 'Info');
        // $this->email->to($email); // It works with this code
        $this->email->bcc($email); // It doesn't work with this code

        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($message);

        $this->email->send();
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have a `to` to be able to `bcc`

Try adding an email to the `to` as well as a `bcc` and it should work.

Comment: Yes, It works that way! I added $this->email->to("") with an empty string and now it works just fine!!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not working. `$this->email->to("")` makes error occur if you're using Mailtrap.io.

Comment: The advice is to add an email to the `to` not leave it empty, try adding a valid email address to the `to` field. Also mailtrap.io is not part of CodeIgniter so you need to check their docs to see if they allow email sending without a `to` address (which I doubt) even if CodeIgniter now allows it (as I haven't used it in 5 years so I am not up on the latest versions).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable **bcc_batch_mode** in email config.
By default is value is FALSE.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't need a `$this->email->to()` all you need to do is set `$config['bcc_batch_mode'] = TRUE;` and then add the emails like `$CI->email->bcc( $bccEmailArray );`. The bcc method does not work like the cc method.